# Dead zones in a bullet trajectory - unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I’m making a small shooter for two players, everyone can shoot. The problem is that when a bullet flies at high speed, then there are certain zones in its trajectory in which it does not touch the object, and accordingly OnTriggerEnter2d does not work there. Here is the bullet flight script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet: MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2d rb;
    public int Player;
    public float speed = 0.4f;
    public Vector3 mode; // Direction of the bullet (Vector3.left, right)
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start ()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        rb.velocity = mode * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you want?

Comment: How to fix it??

Comment: Try this: `Rigidbody2D > Collision Detection > Continuous`

Comment: There is no OnTriggerEnter2D in this script. Did you delete it on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

High speed physics is always a hard nut to crack. Like Iggy mentions you can/should use continuous collision detection.

If you still have issues and still want fast projectiles it get harder. Here are some options.

You can lower the physics time step in time settings (very expensive not recommended but you can test).

You can make the bullet's colliders dynamically bigger. (Might be the simplest easiest solution). When you spawn bullets, calculate based on their speed how long a box collider should be and dynamically position it behind the bullet sorta like a trail (make sure the bullet has moved forward enough to fully expand so you don't hit things behind the player). The box collider's size should be the same as how much distance it moves every frame. That way after moving a tons in a frame all the positions the bullet has been in the frame will trigger a collision on the box collider. For bullet impact and sfx don't spawn them where the bullet is but at the point of contact.

You can calculate if a collision should have happened. (After the physics update check behind the projectile with like a raycast).

You can do your own physics or hybrid. Unity lets you simulate physics when ever you want manually instead of the normal physics update. With more control over that you could add more calculations for fast moving object.